# How to improve efficiency - string representation of an integer using standard incremental routine

Tags: c#

I created a thread for this but then deleted it as I wasnt making myself clear.

This routine (my code) gives me the string representation of currentCombination.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SlowGen
{
    class MyClass
    {
        private List<char> _data = new List<char>();
        private List<char> _c;

        public MyClass(List<char> chars, Int64 currentCombination)
        {
            _c = chars;
            _data.Add(_c[0]);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombination - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i < currentCombination - _c.Count)
                    IncrementFast();
                else
                    Increment();
            }
        }

        public void Increment()
        {
            Increment(0);
        }

        public void Increment(int charIndex)
        {
            if (charIndex + 1 > _data.Count)
                _data.Add(_c[0]);
            else
            {
                if (_data[charIndex] != _c[_c.Count - 1])
                {
                    _data[charIndex] = _c[_c.IndexOf(_data[charIndex]) + 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    _data[charIndex] = _c[0];
                    Increment(charIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        public void IncrementFast()
        {
            IncrementFast(0);
        }
        public void IncrementFast(int charIndex)
        {
            if (charIndex + 1 > _data.Count)
                _data.Add(_c[0]);
            else
            {
                if (_data[charIndex] != _c[_c.Count - 1])
                {
                    _data[charIndex] = _c[_c.Count-1];
                }
                else
                {
                    _data[charIndex] = _c[0];
                    Increment(charIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                string output = string.Empty;
                foreach (char c in _data)
                    output = c + output;
                return output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this example would create A,B,C,AA,AB,AC,BA etc..

```
List<char> a = new List<char>();
a.Add('A');
a.Add('B');
a.Add('C');
MyClass b = new MyClass(a,3);
//b.Value: C
MyClass c = new MyClass(a,4);
//c.Value: AA
```

Now I have this code, which is much more efficient, but the patter differs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] r = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
    for (int i = 0; i <= 120; i++)
    {
        string xx = IntToString(i, r);
        Console.WriteLine(xx);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string IntToString(int value, char[] baseChars)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    int targetBase = baseChars.Length;

    do
    {
        result = baseChars[value % targetBase] + result;
        value = value / targetBase;
    } 
    while (value > 0);

    return result;
}
```

It outputs A,B,C,BA,BB,

I need the sequence of the first section of code with the elegance of the second, can anyone advise?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the behaviour to change for columns besides the units column, as you've no doubt noticed. Since the values for non-units column you see are 1 too high, you need to compensate by subtracting 1 first. Or at least that's what seemed to work here:

```
public static string IntToString(int value, char[] baseChars)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    int targetBase = baseChars.Length;

    do
    {
        int currentValue = value % targetBase;
        result = baseChars[currentValue] + result;
        value = value - currentValue; //possibly not necessary due to integer division rounding down anyway
        value = value / targetBase;
        value = value - 1;
    } 
    while (value > -1);

    return result;
}
```

Here are some worked examples:

6 with targetBase 2 is AAA:

```
6%2 is 0, place A on right, half to 3, subtract 1 to 2
2%2 is 0, place A, half to 1, subtract 1 to 0
0%2 is 0, place A, we're done
```

5 with targetBase 2 is BB:

```
5%2 is 1, place B on right, subtract 1, half to 2, subtract 1 to 1
1%2 is 1, place B, subtract 1, we're done
```

7 with target base 3 is BB:

```
7%3 is 1, place B on right, subtract 1 to 6, 1/3 to 2, subtract 1 to 1
1%3 is 1, place B on right, subtract 1, we're done
```